# I am learning Javascript and I was hoping to get some help on this challenge

Tags: javascript

What does getNameLegenth mean? and does the Name part of it change depending on what the Name is?

```
function getNameLength(name){
    return ;
}
```

Comment: you first need to know how to ask a question [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This function doesn't do anything and returns `undefined`. It doesn't use `name`.

Comment: `getNameLength` is the name of the function. `name` is the name of the only parameter of the function. This means that when you call the function you can supply an argument corresponding to `name`. So yes: the value of `name` will change depending on how you call the function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. From your question, I suggest that you take some time to read more about functions and the pieces that fit together to make them. As 52d5c6af, describes, `getNameLength` is the name of a function here. This name does not change, even if the variable `name` has a different value. It is best to name variables and function to describe what they do. In this case, the function `getNameLength` is used to determine the length of it's parameter `name`. I assume that the exercise is to fill in the details to do this.

Answer (score 0):

getNameLength is the name of the function (which should give you the number of letters in the name). The name part of it is the input of the function. Remember! For each input put into a function, there is exactly one output.

**Example:**

Input -> Output

getNameLength("Bob") -> 3

getNameLength("Jake") -> 4

getNameLength("Tiffany") -> 7